# Copy mssql server 2000 database files

Tags: sql-server

I have two PC that both of them runs MSSQL 2000 server with the same architecture database. Can I stop MSSQL server,  coppy *.ldf and *.mdf files from one PC to another and and then start MSSQL. Without any backup/restore procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx

Be careful with MS SQL Server versions.